# How do I create a Map View in Container View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to create a MapKit View inside the cell of a container view.
The code below causes the app to crash when the view is loaded.

```
let mapView: MKMapView!

mapView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, frame.size.width-20, 100)
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
mapView.zoomEnabled = true
mapView.scrollEnabled = true
contentView.addSubview(mapView)
```

Thanks
(I am using Swift)

Comment: Errors? Stack trace?

Comment: What does the crash say? A crash is a developer tool, not a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never actually initializing your map view.

Comment: Is there documentation that helps with this? Thanks

Comment: `let mapView: MKMapView = MKMapView()`